# What would be C# equivalent for SQL ">" operator in where clause for char column

Tags: c#, sql

working on an c# application i came across something that I don't quite understand.

I have SQL column `KONTO char(15)` and it contains numeric data.
When I run the following query...

```
select * from MyDatabase..GkKon
```

I get this result...

[image]

and thats just fine.

My C# code providing the same result is:

```
using (MyDatabaseEntities db = new MyDatabaseEntities())
{
    var data = db.GkKons.ToList();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
}
```

I came across problem when I tried to select where greater than "01"

```
select * from MyDatabase..GkKon 
where KONTO>'01'
```

SQL did the job and I got

[image]

I tried doing something similar in C# but it gives me syntax error.

```
using (MyDatabaseEntities db = new MyDatabaseEntities())
{
    var data = db.GkKons.Where(x=>x.KONTO>"01").ToList();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
}
```

Because `LINQ` can't use ">" on two strings.
I tried using `SqlCommand` and Parameters to get the data and it works, but I am using `EF` and it seems its causing me problem.

Is there a way to do this using `LINQ` and `EF`?
How does SQL do this "magic"?

Comment: Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netframework-4.8 ?

Comment: I came across String.Compare method but i didn't realised i can use it in LINQ expression like .Where(x=>string.Compare(x.KONTO,"01")==1)

Comment: @BugFinder in your link there is no reference to LINQ. Question is valid. Also it has a very nice answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sql is comparing <s>the byte  value</s> the coallition of the string.
In c# you compare similar to that using the method string.Compare(s1,s2) it returns

```
s1==s2 returns 0  
s1>s2 returns 1  
s1<s2 returns -1
```

something like this:

```
 var data = db.GkKons.Where(x=>string.Compare(x.KONTO,"01")==1).ToList();
```

or if you need the numeric order of the strings you can cast it to an int :

```
 var data = db.GkKons.Where(x=>int.Parse(x.KONTO)>1).ToList();
```

keep in mind that :

```
> string.Compare("0010", "01"); evaluates to
-1
but 
> string.Compare("10", "01"); evaluates to
1
```

---

Edit: changed byte value to coallition as @Gordon Linoff  sugested

Comment: I think you mean *casting* and not *vasting*

Comment: I agree with your answer, I guess we're not sure what the op is actually trying to compare, the number or the string?

Comment: Edited te answer to make the direct answer more aparent, and the int casting as a second one.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, except in the most primitive of databases.  SQL is using the *collation* of the character set in the string to determine the comparison.  In many cases, characters are 7- or 8-bit characters, represented as ASCII codes and the collation is equivalent to a binary comparison.  However, that is a special case.

Comment: Adrian thanks for helping me, that is exactly what I am looking for.I didn't realise i can use string.Compare in LINQ expression.But now when i think about it actually it makes sense.It does compare strings but not directly with > as i thought it should be in expression...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = db.GkKons.Where(x => (x.KONTO > 1)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use linq:
Let's assume that strings is a list of strings ("0","1","2"....)
MajorString is a list of string that are > than the input inserted the compare method.
InpuString is the string input , so every string that is greater than the input string is returned in the majorstring list.
Moreover the compare method return 1 if the first string is greather than the second string.
The output in this case will be : {"2","3"}

```
  List<string> strings = new List<string>();
  strings.Add("0");
  strings.Add("1");
  strings.Add("2");
  strings.Add("3");
  string InputString = "1"
  List<string> MajorString = strings.Where(x => string.Compare(x, InputString ) == 1).ToList();
```